# Square with tabs on each edge

Tags: html, html-table

Here I am, back again with my terrible ASCII skills! Some things in HTML are beyond me and I can't really understand how to put them together. I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
      + + + + + +
      + T  A  B +
    + + + + + + + +
+ + +             + + +
+ T +    MAIN     + T +
+ A +             + A +
+ B +             + B +
+ + +             + + +
    + + + + + + + +
      + T  A  B +
      + + + + + +
```

How this will play out HTML doesn't work in my head. I can't visualize how the heck you'd put something on the top, then left, right, and bottom. It just doesn't make sense. Colspan and rowspan don't seem to be working, and I can't think of a way to do this without a gazillion `<tr>` and `<td>` tags.

Cheers,

Captain Crunch

Comment: "It just doesn't make sense." No, it doesn't. Why on earth would you do this?

Comment: For the sake of learning. This isn't essential, but knowing how would help me to become a better developer.

Comment: Have you seen an example of this anywhere? Post a link to where. Also you need to edit your question and hit CTRL + M and put ALL of your code into the box.

Comment: See, I don't have any code. I'm completely clueless as of how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldntt use tables for layouts. Instead do it with css.

```css
.container{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  margin: 50px;
}

.tab{
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  color: #FFF;
}

.tab:nth-child(1),
.tab:nth-child(2){
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

.tab:nth-child(3),
.tab:nth-child(4){
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
}

.tab:nth-child(1){
  top: -50%;
}

.tab:nth-child(2){
  bottom: -50%;
}

.tab:nth-child(3){
  right: -50%;
}

.tab:nth-child(4){
  left: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
  <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
  <div class="tab">Tab 4</div>
</div>
```